# Running python script in a node server?

Tags: python, node.js

My younger brother has made a small rock, scissor and paper python game running in console.
I want to host it on my own domain, running on a digitalOcean droplet. I have no more experience with python, than knowing some syntax and use-cases.

I guess it is almost impossible to run python code in the browser, so my guess is that I have to set up a server. However, due to me not knowing python whatsoever I won't throw my self into learning django or flask for the sake of this.

Can I create a java backend, or even better a node server running with express that can somehow communicate with the python script? If so, how should this be achieved in the easiest way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are Python implementations available that run in the browser. That is likely the best approach to your problem. Turning a Python script into a basic web app with Flask wouldn't be too hard either, the difficulty is that a console app with its stream-based I/O model is fundamentally different from a web app with a request-based I/O model.

You can of course create a Java or Node backend that runs the Python script. The general approach goes a little something like this:

- start the Python script as a separate process. You capture the stdin, stdout, stderr streams.
- when the backend receives a request, it writes input to the captured stdin, and responds with captured data from stdout/stderr

The difficulty is managing a Python process that persists over multiple requests, because the Python script is stateful. You  can't share one Python process across all requests because different users will have different program states. So you need to start one Python process per user/session, and shut down old processes if the session is inactive. You may also want to limit the maximum number of concurrent processes, because the memory and CPU requirements can add up.

So managing these processes safely can involve a lot of complexity. Purely client-side solutions like running Python in the browser might be more difficult to set up, but they avoid these complications entirely.